# Load and cache Groovy scripts and classes from a String

Tags: groovy

I am integrating Groovy on my Java project to allow it to load Groovy code at runtime. The idea is to keep some of business rules on a database or memory cache and reload them at runtime.

However, I can't find a method that reads from a *String* or *InputStream* and supports both scripts and classes.

The [groovy documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/integrating.html) shows 3 methods of loading scripts and classes at runtime but none allow to load both scripts and classes from a String input:

- **GroovyShell** supports caching, but has Thread safety limitations and only runs scripts
- **GroovyClassLoader** loads Strings and runs classes, but only caches File inputs
- **GroovyScriptEngine** runs classes and scripts, supports caching and reloading, but only reads files

Comment: when you are talking about `runs classes` - is it about class with `static void main` method?  could you show an examples of code that you want to run?

Comment: The idea is to read a bunch of rules defined elsewhere (db or a file), wrap them on a class or script and run them. It's basically a poor man's DSL.

Comment: Use groovyshell. It could run classes as well. Thread limitation - only if you implement it with a limit.